# How can I remove the excess CSS classes that Smelte.js generates?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am working on a project with Svelte and the material design library **[Smelte](https://github.com/matyunya/smelte)**:

```
<script>

const currency = [
    { value: 1, text: "EUR" },
    { value: 2, text: "GBP" },
    { value: 3, text: "USD" }];

</script>

<Smelte.Select label="Currency" class="bg-transparent inline-block">
    <div slot="options" class="elevation-1">
        {#each items as item}
            <div class="p-2">{item.text}</div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</Smelte.Select>
```

The problem is that Smelte generates a lot of HTML elements to which it adds a lot of classes I don't need:

```
<div class="mt-0 relative text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-100 select ">
  <label class="absolute top-0 label-transition block px-4 pointer-events-none cursor-text svelte-81hn54" bgcolor="white">EUR</label> <input readonly="" class="transition   px-4 -t text-black dark:text-gray-100 w-full border  bg-transparent  transition  caret-primary-500   border-gray-600  border-l-0 border-t-0 border-r-0 pb-1  cursor-pointer  transition   px-4 -t text-black dark:text-gray-100 w-full border  bg-transparent  transition  caret-primary-500   border-gray-600  border-l-0 border-t-0 border-r-0 pb-1  cursor-pointer"> 
  <div class="absolute right-0 top-0 pb-2 pr-4 pt-4 text-gray-700 z-10"><i aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons icon text-xl transition svelte-zzky5a" style="color: default">arrow_drop_down</i></div>
  <div class="line absolute bottom-0 left-0 w-full bg-gray-600 svelte-xd9zs6 hidden">
    <div class="mx-auto w-0 svelte-xd9zs6" style="height: 2px; transition: width 0.2s ease 0s;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wish I had `<div class="absolute right-0 top-0 pr-4 z-10">` instead of `<div class="absolute right-0 top-0 pb-2 pr-4 pt-4 text-gray-700 z-10">`.

How can I achieve the desired result (*without* making changes to the node_modules)?

Comment: You should probably ask directly to the maintener of this library on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the ***[source of the `select` smelte component](https://github.com/matyunya/smelte/blob/master/src/components/Select/Select.svelte)***. You'll see a few props that may be of help.

> No really, go read the [smelte `select` code](https://github.com/matyunya/smelte/blob/master/src/components/Select/Select.svelte) and look for the props before allowing your eyes to read further
>
> (keyphrase:`export let`)

---

> 

---

Here's the props that describe the classes for the component:

```
  export let classes = classesDefault;
  export let optionsClasses = optionsClassesDefault;
```

the default for `select` is described as follows

```
  const optionsClassesDefault = "absolute left-0 bg-white rounded elevation-3 w-full z-20 dark:bg-dark-500";
  const classesDefault = "cursor-pointer relative pb-4";
```

So, here's an overwrite of the const defaults with those very same defualts but from the perspective of the parent component instead:

```
<script>
    import { Select } from "smelte";

    const items = [
    { value: 1, text: "One" },
    { value: 2, text: "Two" },
    { value: 3, text: "Three" },
    { value: 4, text: "Four" },
    ];
</script>

<Select label="My Select List" {items} classes="cursor-pointer relative pb-4" optionsClasses="absolute left-0 bg-white rounded elevation-3 w-full z-20 dark:bg-dark-500" />
```

You can adapt this idea to your specifications. Let me know if this works for you!

*As always, it's super helpful to refer to the source code of your dependencies to see what they are truly capable of.  Svelte components, **given their forthright syntax** never fail to present good opportunities to practice code-reading to look for props you can leverage.*

---

**A friendly tip**:

- *Your question, "How can I remove the excess CSS classes that Smelte.js generates?"* **does not describe** what you are trying to do. It **does not** describe your problem. Your title describes your thought-process. It describes your proposed solution.*
- *When you started working on the component and ran into your problem, the very first thought in your mind **was not**, "Hey, I've got specifically excessive CSS here! how do I fix it?",*
- *instead you looked at the screen and said, "Hey, my eyes tell me the spacing isn't right between these two things! I'd like them to be closer together vertically. I have to change the top and bottom padding on these.  How do I change the padding of this?*
- *"How do I change the margin or padding of a smeltejs component?" describes the problem you're trying to solve a bit better*
- *Just spent a lot of time writing an answer about how to check that CSS tree-shaking is working and how to configure it if it isn't.  I just deleted 60mins of work and validation on that, and added 30mins more to give you the common sveltian method*
- *summary: ask questions, not solutions.  Hope this helps too!?*